# How adjust email field width and height in Contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on creating a blog in `wordpress` where I used a `contact form 7` plugin. Here the email text box looking different. [check here](http://www.ammanpaidikondala.com/contact-us-2/).

I am not aware of the coding stuff. How do I make email text box look like other text boxes? Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: "I am not aware of the coding stuff" - not exactly a great line to include in your question on StackOverflow....

Answer (score 0):

The reason it currently looks different is this part of your CSS code (line 195 of `wp-content/themes/simple-catch/style.css`):

```
/* Form */
input[type=text], input.text, input.title, textarea, select {
    background-color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color:#aaa;
    padding:9px 10px;
    font-style:italic;
    width: 368px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e5e5e5 inset;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

As you can see, the selector doesn't include an input with a type of "email" and your email input doesn't have a class `text` or `title`, so this rule isn't triggered on the email field.

The solution is very simple - change the selector to something like this:

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], input.text, input.title, textarea, select {
```

Now the styling should be applied on the email input as well as on the other text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin has applied the styles you see to `input[type='email']` and not to `input[type='text']`

Do you have custom CSS plugin installed on your wordpress? If so, you need only give the same properties to `input[type='email']` as are applied to `input[type='text']`. You can find these styles in developer mode in your browser